# Parse data in Angular 2 with Typescript

Tags: angularjs, parsing, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular (IONIC). How can I get specifically userId or id from this code?

`his.response = data.`

//How to access Json keys

Response :

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in pure Javascript, it has nothing to do with Ionic framework.

If the received data is a json object you need to convert it to Javascript object with

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then you can access it's keys in the following manner:

```
data['userId'];
data['id'];

// or
data.userId;
data.id;
```